# Show that the sequence of random variables $X_n\sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ does not converge in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

I want to show that the sequence given by $X_n\sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ does not converge in probability. This is part (d) of the following question.

[image]

Below is the solution I've seen. Shouldn't it be $P(|X_n-X_{n+1}|\leq 1)=1$ because $X_{n}$ and $X_{n+1}$ could both be zero? I don't quite get the argument after that either. Can someone please explain?

[image]

Comment: After your edit: this changes a **lot**. Note that whichever of the two sequences is picked, two consecutive terms of the sequence are always different... either $0,1$ or $1,0$. So no, $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ cannot be both zero.

Comment: @ClementC. Ah thanks. I now see that's true because of the sequences but doesn't that mean $X_n$ is not Bernoulli(1/2) then? Because if it were, we could get two consecutive 0's?

Comment: Each $X_n$ is Bernoulli. (Its marginal distribution is Bernoulli.) But the $X_n$'s are not independent at all -- if I give you the value of $X_1$, you now the values of all $X_n$'s. Note that $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are *not* the same random variable: each of them, separately, is a Bernoulli random variable, but they are not independent.

Comment: @ClementC. Aha I completely misinterpreted the setup. Many thanks for clearing that up. Am I right in now thinking that no matter what $X$ is, if $\epsilon=1/4$, say, then either $|X_n-X|\geq \epsilon$ or $|X_{n+1}-X|\geq \epsilon$? Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Yes, you are right: use the triangle inequality to show that (actually, also works for $\varepsilon = 1/2$). Now, since this is true for any $X$, there is not way there exists a specific r.v. $X$ such that $\Pr[\lvert X_n-X\rvert \geq \varepsilon] \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.